# Logging in to school website using htmlUnit

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to make an application for my school website (reggienet.illinoisstate.edu), but I'm having trouble getting entering the login and having it stored in the cookies that I am logged in. I've scoured the web and tried everything I could find, but nothing is working I'm totally lost.

Here is the code that I have right now

```
public void login()
{
    HtmlPage currentPage = null;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    try
    {
        webClient = reggieLogin(webClient, keyboard);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        currentPage = webClient.getPage(""https://reggienet.illinoisstate.edu/portal"");
    }
    catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String pageSource = currentPage.asXml();

    System.out.print(pageSource);
}


private WebClient reggieLogin(WebClient webClient, Scanner keyboard) throws Exception
{
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("https://account.illinoisstate.edu/centrallogin/"); //Load page at the STRING address.
    HtmlInput username = currentPage.getElementByName("username"); //Find element called loginuser for username
    System.out.print("ULID:  ");
    username.setValueAttribute(keyboard.nextLine()); //Set value for username
    HtmlInput password = currentPage.getElementByName("password"); //Find element called loginpassword for password
    System.out.print("Password:  ");
    password.setValueAttribute(keyboard.nextLine()); //Set value for password
    HtmlButtonInput submitBtn = currentPage.getElementByName("submit"); //Find element called Submit to submit form.
    currentPage = submitBtn.click(); //Click on the button.

    return webClient;
}
```

Can anybody offer any help, or can anybody see what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Perhaps you need to set JavaScriptEnabled to true? Just wondering, as most modern websites need javascript enabled.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and unfortunately that didn't work, it still doesnt recognize that i'm logged in

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Selenium library to interact with websites. It has methods for editing browser cookies. [Here is a link to its java documentation.](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn@7074/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html)

Comment: Looks promising, I'll give it a try! Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't what I was looking for, as it requires an external browser.  I'm looking for something that will work as a webscraper in android studio

Comment: Oh sorry, I have never done android development. @Andrew